# How can I query a many-many relationship into a collection-entity response effectively?

Tags: sql, backend

I have the following tables, `tasks`, `categories`, `tasks_categories`, and they are in many-to-many relationship.

```sql
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('completed', 'incomplete');

drop table if exists tasks;
create table if not exists tasks(
    id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    -- created_at timestamptz not null,
    updated_at timestamptz not null,
    status status not null,
    primary key(id)
);

drop table if exists categories;
create table if not exists categories(
    id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    name varchar(256) not null,
    updated_at timestamptz not null,
    primary key(id)
);

drop table if exists tasks_categories;
create table if not exists tasks_categories(
    id int GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    tasks_id int not null,
    categories_id int not null,
    primary key(id),
    foreign key(tasks_id) references tasks,
    foreign key(categories_id) references categories
);
```

I want to response in the following structure in my tasks route, as categories always exists with tasks.  Use javascript as an example to denote the data structure

```js
[{
  id: 1,
  name: "Make dinner",
  updated_at: "xxxx-xx-xx",
  status: "incomplete",
  categories: [{
    id: 3,
    name: "cooking",
    updated_at: "xxxx-xx-xx"
  }]
}]
```

How can I do that with sql? Right now I can only think of querying in the steps

- `select * from tasks`;
- Use for-loop to iterate the result of the previous query, use `id` of each `tasks` object to filter the inner join result of `categories` and `tasks_categories`

I guess I will have to make a lot of database queries as the list growth, and it might be costly. Is there any better alternative? Or should I just let the client fetch more?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks will be your left most table, task_categories your middle table, and categories your right table. This will return one record for every category per task.

```
SELECT
    t.id
    ,t.name
    ,t.updated_at
    ,t.status
    ,c.id
    ,c.name
    ,c.updated_at
FROM Task t
LEFT JOIN Task_Categories tc ON
    t.ID = tc.task_id
LEFT JOIN Categories c ON
    tc.categories_id = c.id
```